# Drag a Point to new location polar heatmap, point series

Tags: lightningchart

I cannot move/drag a data point to a new location. I can create a point using

const pointSeries = polarChart
.addPointSeries()
.setMouseInteractions(false)
.setCursorEnabled(false)
.setAutoScrollingEnabled(false)
.setPointSize(10);

`const pointSeriesData: PolarPoint[] = []; pointSeriesData.push({ angle, amplitude })`your text `pointSeries.setData(pointSeriesData)`
Is that possible I can drag that data point to a new location on polar chart?

I tried to explore point series but I couldn't figure out.

Comment: Hi, could you add more information about your use case and specifically why dragging polar points is needed? This will me understand better that kind of solution to suggest, as it is not a very simple case.
For example, details like the number of polar points (is it just 1-5 points or 1000s?) is critical.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have figured out the solution. I am using Polar points as markers so I need to drag them to the specific point (business requirement). I achieved that with mouse drag event.

Comment: Well that's good to hear. If you don't mind the effort, I would be interested in learning more how you got this working, because I would imagine implementing logic for dragging point series using events API to be quite tricky at the moment. I've recently worked on related feature improvements (polar coordinate translations) that will be coming out in future LCJS versions, which might be interesting for you too. Also, Stack Overflow community appreciates explaining solutions even if you found them by yourself :)